# jQuery Knob hover animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-knob

I want to animate the Knob circle that it fills up on hovering. I'm new to Knob so i have no idea where my error is or if i even have the right direction. Right now it does not even show a circle :(

Basically i just want to have a circle around an icon that fills up on hovering. Maybe i can achieve that easier?

**This is the sollution of it plus a little fix that i will start and stop at the right values, so you can interupt the animation without breaking it**

the HTML:

```
<input type="text" value="0" id="circle" />
```

the Javascript:

```
$(function() {
$('.circle').knob({
    min: '0',
    max: '100',
    readOnly: true,
    displayInput: false
});

$('.circle').parent().hover( function() {console.log("hover");
                $({ value: $('.circle').val() }).animate(
                    { value: 100 }, 
                    {   duration: 300,
                        easing: 'swing',
                        progress: function() {
                          $('.circle').val(Math.round(this.value)).trigger('change');
                        }
                     });
             }, function() {
                $({ value: $('.circle').val() }).animate(
                    { value: 0 }, 
                    {
                        duration: 300,
                        easing: 'swing',
                        progress: function() {
                            $('.circle').val(Math.round(this.value)).trigger('change');
                        }
                     });
                });
});
```

Here is the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dWsuP/4/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to change the hover handler to the parent of #circle or change displayInput to true

```
$(function() {
$('#circle').knob({
    min: '0',
    max: '100',
    readOnly: true,
    displayInput: false
});
//$('#circle').parent() is the new div that contains the input and the canvas
$('#circle').parent().hover( function() {
                $({ value: 0 }).animate(
                    { value: 100 }, 
                    {   duration: 1000,
                        easing: 'swing',
                        progress: function() {
                          $('#circle').val(Math.round(this.value)).trigger('change');
                        }
                     });
             }, function() {
                $({ value: 100 }).animate(
                    { value: 0 }, 
                    {
                        duration: 1000,
                        easing: 'swing',
                        progress: function() {
                            $('#circle').val(Math.round(this.value)).trigger('change');
                        }
                     });
                });
});//you need to close with ');'
```

you need to include the knob.js in the fiddle or else you get a '404 Not Found' error and include jquery or else you get this error 'Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined'
http://jsfiddle.net/dWsuP/1/

Comment: Well it works like i want it with a little exeption: when the circle is not full when you take our mouse out of it (when you dont wait for the animation to finish) then it will start running down from 100, but i think i have an idea how i can fix this.